# Spivak alike books for Probability and/or Statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

I am looking for a Probability/Statistics book with an style alike to that of Spivak's Calculus, that is, a book with the following characteristics:

1. Directed more towards Math majors rather than applied majors(engineers, economists, physicists).
2. Every theorem, or almost every theorem is proven rigorously.
3. Even though the book is very rigourous mathmatically, it gives a very deep intuitive understanding of the subject. I don't want merely to have a collection of formulas that work, but I want to know why they work, and what they mean.
   Also, I when I say rigourous I don't mean technical or formal, the book doesn't need to use lots of technical words, it can be informal, as long as the proofs are proved rigorously.

Rigorous proofs and deep understanding... Could you please reference me to a book like that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Fellers classic text on probability (especially volume 1) should fit well!

Comment: Thanks kjetil, I am going to search it

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Dudley's "Real Analysis and Measure Theory." The first half of the book is general measure theory; the second half deals with probability spaces in particular. (I believe they were explicitly marked as Part I and Part II of the book in the original; the revised edition might not preserve that distinction.) It's a great book, though you might want to start with the third chapter, which begins the subject in earnest, and consider the first two chapters on basic set theory and real analysis as appendices to be referred to as necessary.

Comment: Thank you, however I found Dudley to be extremely tecnical, and not very intuitive. It is a book I might consider reading in the future, however I find it extremely hard as a first year college student

Comment: Some of the exercises go into a bit more of the intuitive bits (for example, I remember a few in an early chapter about what can happen when probabilities are assumed only to be finitely additive). Unfortunately, measure theory is a rather fiddly subject. Finding a book that's simultaneously very rigorous and has digressions on the intuitive notion is going to be tricky; you're usually left on your own for the latter after a certain point.